# Existe curl em NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

Bom é o seguinte eu precisava de alguma função que me servisse de "curl", para utilizar no nodejs.

Existe alguma function, que faça o equivalente ao curl no php?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja a documentação para um exemplo completo e como usar o módulo de HTTP:
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.request

Também tem esse exemplo

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Então sim, existe algo equivalente.

Comment: Consegui utilizar! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja necessário alguma funcionalidade exclusiva do libcurl, existe um pacote que serve de `binding` para o libcurl no Node.js chamado [`node-libcurl`](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl).

*(Eu sou o autor do mesmo)*

Exemplo de uso:

```
const { Curl } = require('node-libcurl');

const curl = new Curl();

curl.setOpt('URL', 'www.google.com');
curl.setOpt('FOLLOWLOCATION', true);

curl.on('end', function (statusCode, data, headers) {
  console.info(statusCode);
  console.info('---');
  console.info(data.length);
  console.info('---');
  console.info(this.getInfo( 'TOTAL_TIME'));

  this.close();
});

curl.on('error', function (error, errorCode) {
  // faça algo com error
  this.close()
});
curl.perform();
```